# PyYAML loader with duplicate keys

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

Using PyYAML for loading a YAML (large) file which has duplicate keys. I would like to preserve all keys and would modify duplicate key according to project need. But it seems PyYAML is silently overwrites results with the last key and not getting a chance to modify it as my need (loss of information), resulting in this dict: `{'blocks':{'a':'b2:11 c2:22'}}`

simple example YAML:

```
import yaml
given_str = '''
   blocks:
      a:
        b1:1
        c1:2
    
      a:
        b2:11
        c2:22'''
p = yaml.load(given_str)
```

**How can I load the YAML with duplicate keys so that I get a chance to recursively traverse it and modify keys as my need.**  I need to load YAML and then transfer it into a database.

Comment: This is not a YAML file (please note YML is a different, XML based, format), as in YAML keys for a mapping need to be unique. Do you really want to write such a file? What software relies on duplicate keys to be available?

Comment: This is representation of the actual yml. We are getting `yml` s from 3rd party vendors which aren't following rules of avoiding duplicate keys (valid yml). My plan is to load them and change the key. But I'm not getting a chance w/ PYyaml.

Comment: Sorry I had not properly read that you wanted to change the duplicate keys, but that you wanted to write out an update file with duplicate keys after changing something. It looks like the 3rd party vendors don't know about YAML, and I hope the multiline scalars `b1:1 c1:2` are not supposed to be mappings.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input YAML has no merge keys ('<<'), no tags and no comments you want
to preserve, you can use the following:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from pathlib import Path
from collections.abc import Hashable

file_in = Path('input.yaml')

class MyConstructor(ruamel.yaml.constructor.SafeConstructor):
    def construct_mapping(self, node, deep=False):
        """deep is True when creating an object/mapping recursively,
        in that case want the underlying elements available during construction
        """
        if not isinstance(node, ruamel.yaml.nodes.MappingNode):
            raise ConstructorError(
                None, None, f'expected a mapping node, but found {node.id!s}', node.start_mark,
            )
        total_mapping = self.yaml_base_dict_type()
        if getattr(node, 'merge', None) is not None:
            todo = [(node.merge, False), (node.value, False)]
        else:
            todo = [(node.value, True)]
        for values, check in todo:
            mapping: Dict[Any, Any] = self.yaml_base_dict_type()
            for key_node, value_node in values:
                # keys can be list -> deep
                key = self.construct_object(key_node, deep=True)
                # lists are not hashable, but tuples are
                if not isinstance(key, Hashable):
                    if isinstance(key, list):
                        key = tuple(key)
                if not isinstance(key, Hashable):
                    raise ConstructorError(
                        'while constructing a mapping',
                        node.start_mark,
                        'found unhashable key',
                        key_node.start_mark,
                    )

                value = self.construct_object(value_node, deep=deep)
                if key in mapping:
                    pat = key + '_undup_{}'
                    index = 0
                    while True:
                        nkey = pat.format(index)
                        if nkey not in mapping:
                            key = nkey
                            break
                        index += 1
                mapping[key] = value
            total_mapping.update(mapping)
        return total_mapping

 
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
yaml.default_flow_style = False
yaml.Constructor = MyConstructor
data = yaml.load(file_in)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
blocks:
  a: b1:1 c1:2
  a_undup_0: b2:11 c2:22
```

Please note that the values for both `a` keys are multiline plain scalars. For `b1` and `c1` to be a key
the mapping value indicator (`:`, the colon) needs to be followed by a whitespace character:

```
a:
  b1: 1
  c1: 2
```

Comment: I used the SafeConstructor and `typ='safe'`, so this will get you the C based scanner and parser, which should speed up loading the files by an ordder of magnitude compared to the code in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

After reading many forums, I think best solution is create a wrapper for yml loader (removing duplicates) is the solution. @Anthon - any comment?

```
import yaml
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

####### Preserving Duplicate ###################
def parse_preserving_duplicates(input_file):
    class PreserveDuplicatesLoader(yaml.CLoader):
        pass

    def map_constructor(loader, node, deep=False):
        """Walk tree, removing degeneracy in any duplicate keys"""
        keys = [loader.construct_object(node, deep=deep) for node, _ in node.value]
        vals = [loader.construct_object(node, deep=deep) for _, node in node.value]
        key_count = Counter(keys)
        data = defaultdict(dict)  # map all data removing duplicates 
        c = 0
        for key, value in zip(keys, vals):
            if key_count[key] > 1:
                data[f'{key}{c}'] = value
                c += 1
            else:
                data[key] = value
            return data

    PreserveDuplicatesLoader.add_constructor(yaml.resolver.BaseResolver.DEFAULT_MAPPING_TAG,
                                             map_constructor)
    return yaml.load(input_file, PreserveDuplicatesLoader)
##########################################################
with open(inputf, 'r') as file:
    fp = parse_preserving_duplicates(input_file)
```